# pass variable via GET to decide if UTF-8 will be used

Tags: php, utf-8, get

So the idea was this, if i use **example.php?u=8**, UTF-8 will be used.
I thought this would do the trick.

```
<?php
  $u=($_GET["u"]);  // 8 is utf8
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<?php if ($u=8): ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif ?>

      <title>just any title</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously I am doing something completely, wrong, since it doesnt even give me the variable.

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison. It should be `if ($u == 8)`.

Comment: Also, to prevent a warning about undefined index, you should use `isset($_GET['u'])`.

Comment: thanks! (i feel a bit stupid now)